# Change from re.findall(regex, text) to nltk.Text.findall(regex)

Tags: python, regex, nltk

Using Python and the NLTK I have written a regex to find words with start with a capital letter in a body of text but aren't at the beginning of a sentence.

Initially I was using it as follow:

```
[w for w in text if re.findall(r'(?<!\.\s)\b[A-Z][a-z]\b',w)]
```

the variable text is created using the treebank corpus as follows:

```
 >>> def concat(lists):
    biglist = [ ]
    while len(lists)>0:
        biglist = biglist+lists[0]
        lists=lists[1:]
    return biglist
>>> tbsents = concat(treebank.sents()[200:250])
>>> text = nltk.Text(tbsents)
```

However this doesn't seem to work, it still returns words that are at the beginning of sentences.
So I thought I would try using the text.findall() function instead.
I ran the following and it returned all the words with capital letters as required.

```
>>> text.findall("<[A-Z][a-z]{3,}>")
```

The problem I have is I don't how to get the first bit of the regex in to the <..> format required for the second function, and if I do will it even work or am I taking completely the wrong approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing with the first list comprehension: you're using findall on each individual word, *not* on the text itself.

The simplest way to do what you want with the treebank corpus, since you already have them divided by sentence, is:

```
import itertools
non_starting_words = list(itertools.chain(*[s[1:] for s in treebank.sents()]))
uppercase_words = [w for w in non_starting_words if w[0].isupper()]
```

Perhaps this is what you wanted to do with the "concat" function, but that just got a list of all words- it didn't remove the first of each sentence. If you do want to concatenate a list of lists, a much better way is the list(itertools.chain(*lists)) thing I did above.

ETA: Given that you have to work with a list of tokens, the best solution is then not to use regexes but rather:

```
punctuation_marks = ".!?"
first_word = True
uppercase_words = []

for w in text:
    if not first_word and re.match("[A-Z][a-z]*$", w):
        uppercase_words.append(w)
    first_word = w in punctuation_marks

print uppercase_words
```

Comment: Yep I realised what I had done with the first line, but I included it as the regex works the way I want. Unfortunately the concat function and the text = nltk.text(tbsents) section was supplied and I am required to find proper nouns in the 'text' variable.

Comment: I hadn't realized this was an assignment. Are you sure your first line works? When I reproduce your code precisely, I get ['He', 'Mr.', 'He', 'Co.', 'Mr.', 'He', 'He', 'So', 'Mr.', 'Mr.', 'Mr.', 'In'] as the list.

Comment: This is how I tested it:

>>> re.findall(r'(?<!\.\s)\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b', "the Monkey was. They love Chik and Chop. WOws and WOnt and WOOZ")
['Monkey', 'Chik', 'Chop']

Comment: In that test, you are applying it to the entire sentence. In the code in your question, you are applying it to each individual word- there is a huge difference.

Comment: That is what I realised so I thought I would do it using the second method with the text.findall(), but does that do the same?

Comment: It doesn't for a few reasons. NLTK.findall() is a very poor function because it doesn't even return anything, it just prints out the words. It also forces you to use <'s for your tokens. I added a much better solution above.

Comment: `list(itertools.chain(*[s[1:] for s in treebank.sents()]))` can be expressed simpler as `[w for s in treebank.sents() for w in s[1:]]`.